# Thread-specific variables when using parallel algorithms

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, stl, thread-local

I was wondering about the following thing: Sometimes when executing an operation on multiple items, a buffer is necessary for example for storing an intermediate result. When operating in a single threaded manner, this is straightforward. However, when processing the work items in parallel, each thread needs its own buffer to write to. I would probably not want to create this buffer inside the body of my functor because this would mean it gets allocated for each iteration, which might be slow and is unnecessary.

Therefore, I was now wondering how to achieve this when using the parallel algorithms from the C++ STL. I checked the documentation on cppreference and unfortunately couldn't find a definitive answer. It does state though that for the overload taking an execution policy, the functor needs to be copy-constructible. Consequently, I would have assumed that the functor passed to the algorithm gets copied for each thread that is involved. However, I did the following little test and this doesn't seem to be the case (Windows, Visual Studio):

```
struct Functor
{
  auto operator()(int const&) -> void
  {
    std::strstream x;
    x << GetCurrentThreadId() << ": " << buffer.data() << std::endl;
    std::cout << x.str();
  }
  std::vector<int> buffer{10};
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> y(10, 5);
  std::for_each(std::execution::par, y.begin(), y.end(), Functor{});

  return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
46324: 0000000000DB76A0
45188: 0000000000DB76A0
```

So either what I assumed is not the case, or my test is flawed. I printed the pointer to the data section of the vector member of my functor along with the thread ID. I would have assumed that this pointer varies when the thread ID varies. This is not the case. The same pointer is printed from different threads.

Is my test valid? If so, is there another way that I can have a variable in my functor that is instantiated once per thread? Of course I could create a `thread_local` variable in the body of my functor, but I kind of dislike this approach because as far as I understand that variable would have static lifetime meaning it would only be destructed once the lifetime of the thread it was allocated in ends.

Comment: "I would probably not want to create this buffer inside the body of my functor because this would mean it gets allocated for each iteration, which might be slow and is unnecessary." - premature optimization... If you use ordinary array instead of `std::vector`, the allocation is basically free.

Comment: "Consequently, I would have assumed that the functor passed to the algorithm gets copied for each thread that is involved" just because it must be copyable does not imply that the algorithm copies it always. Just because you found in this case that it does not copy, you cannot conlude that it would never copy. In general functors passed to alogirthms can be copied by the algorithm. Though I also do not know a good answer, because with singlethreaded you can simply store the state outside of the functor

Comment: You can use an `unordered_map` with thread ids as keys and buffers as values.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Relevant: [Unless otherwise specified, function objects passed into parallel algorithms ... shall not rely on the identity of the provided objects.](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#user-1.sentence-1)

Comment: @DanielLangr interesting. Not sure if I understand it completely. How about lambdas with reference captures

Comment: @Quimby: Of course using an `std::array` would be free, but that only works in cases where the size is known at compile time, and this sometimes is just not the case. I think calling it premature optimization would require to look at a specific use case. However, my question is of a general nature, and I hope we can agree that in general doing many allocations can definitely have a negative impact performance in *some* cases.

Comment: @bweber Okay, in that case I agree, it's a good question.

Comment: @DanielLangr: I think reference captures are only an option if multiple threads have to *read* the same value. For *writing*, access would have to be synchronized which again would create contention and hurt the performance of the parallelization. So I think performance-wise what you would need really is a variable that is somehow thread-specific, i.e. is copied once per thread. Then each thread can write to its copy without having to think about what the others are doing.

Comment: If you want some kind of cache or buffer to be shared then you have to synchronize accesses to it. If you want it to be for each thread separately then thread_local makes sense. If the buffer is needed per problem then keep it together with that problem. On any case do not put it as state owned by copyable functor as the chance that standard library may copy it is perhaps given as reason why not to do it.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Well, if the standard library *would* copy it, then all would be well ;) I am aware of `thread_local`, and I have explained my concerns in the questions. Maybe they are unwarranted, I don't know. But as far as I understand, if multiple places in the codebase do this, then all this memory may stick around indefinitely and only gets freed once the application gets terminated. That's something I would like to avoid.

Comment: @DanielLangr: My first comment was referring to your mention of lambdas using reference capture. The map suggestion again has the problem of synchonization, I think. Multiple threads *reading* from the same map would be fine, but I don't know the involved threads beforehand. This means a thread has to insert its buffer into the map the first time it processes an item. Consequently, I have mixed read/write operations from different threads which would again require me to synchronize *all* operations on the map (read and write).

Comment: @bweber I agree with that. However, with concurrent hash maps, once each thread adds its record into the hash table, then only lookup is performed, which basically requires only reading operations. See my answer for details.

Comment: The thread_local is deallocated when thread ends not when program ends. If you need to clear it early then you can do it. That can be optimization or pessimization depending on concrete problem.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Yes, however, the threads *may* stick around until the program ends. How could I free the thread-local variables earlier? Since I am not really in control of the threads, I don't see how.

Comment: Your test may be flawed. https://godbolt.org/z/aoohz8G81

Comment: Everything that is let to stick around will stick around. C++ program can at least be designed to automate mopping things up using RAII. The thread_local does not mean that we can't pass reference of it to other threads, just that we will lose accesses being embarrassingly parallel and gain risk to have dangling reference by doing so. Things like std::execution::par ... are anyway hints and profiling can show that results are garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table of buffers that is indexed by thread ids. In such a case, each thread will have its own buffer. A simple demo implementation that uses a mutex-protected hash table might look like as follows:

```
std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, std::vector<int>> map;
std::mutex m;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> y(10, 5);
  std::for_each(std::execution::par, y.begin(), y.end(),
    [](int)
    {
      thread_local std::vector<int>& buffer =
        []() -> auto& 
        { 
          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
          auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();        
          auto& buffer = map[id];
          return buffer;
        }();

      buffer.resize(10);
      std::cout << id << " : " << buffer.data() << std::endl;
    }
  );
  map.clear();
}
```

Note that the mutex is locked only once per thread, subsequent uses of buffers don't require the hash table.

Comment: I agree that your solution works. I am, however, a bit afraid that the now required synchonization is somewhat detrimental to performance, something that were not the case if the buffer just got copied for each thread initially.

Comment: @bweber I completely rewrote the answer to use a better solution where a mutex for a hash table is locked only once per thread.

Comment: What does your implementation do better than `thread_local std::vector<int> /* no reference */ buffer`?

Comment: @n.m. OP specifically said that `thread_local` vectors (buffers) do not suit them. Generally, this solution gives you control of those "thread-local" data even after the threads are finished.

Comment: You are using thread_local buffer references, which, as far as I understand OP's stated reasons, has all the same problems as thread_local buffers, and then some. OP doesn't need to extend the lifetime of the buffer past that of the thread, quite the opposite is true.

Comment: @n.m. It hasn't been specified why OP cares about the lifetime of thread-local variables. I suppose that those buffers may be large and then OP wants to destroy them once the algorithm is finished. In such a case, there is no problem with thread-local references. But those buffers can be released from the main thread as shown in my code. If the buffers themselves would be thread-local, then there is no way how to destroy them from the main thread.

Comment: I see what you mean. Your solution makes it easy to free the buffers once the parallel algorithm has ended, but what if you need to run the exact same algorithm again? Use a different map?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think the problem is that this only works once. If the parallel for_each is in a function, the first call will work as the thread_local variables are still uninitialized. Then at the end of the function, the map will be deallocated. Now the pointers in the thread_local variables point to invalid memory. When the function is called the second time, it crashes if you try to write to the buffer, as the thread_local pointers are not initialized again. You have to consider that the threads do not get destroyed once one parallel algorithm is finished. They are part of a thread pool.

Comment: I reproduced the behaviour here on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/WcreM7cn3 You can execute the program there and you will see that it crashes when the function is called the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage a pool of buffers, and then have each invocation allocate a buffer from the pool, or create a new one if the pool is empty, and release the buffer when it's done.  The number of buffers you allocate will then equal the number of concurrent threads used.

A pool of buffers can be a singly-linked stack, which is the simplest possible lock-free data structure.

If the operation of your functor is so small that you'd worry about contention on the pool, then you can make an array of 16 pools indexed by a hash of the thread ID.

Comment: I understand the first part of you answer, but not the last paragraph. Could you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "make an array of 16 pools indexed by a hash of the thread ID" and how that would prevent the need for locking?

Comment: There is no need for locking at all, since you would use a lock-free stack in all cases.  16 pools makes it less likely that threads would interfere with each other by accessing the same pool at the same time.  If you space them apart properly then you reduce cache line contention as well.